# How to create typo3 template for content element?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have created a new content element for slider. I have added these codes in my typo3 setup

`EXT:rapigo\Configuration\TsConfig\Page\Mod\WebLayout\mod.tsconfig`

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common {
    elements {
        rapigo_home_slider {
            iconIdentifier = content-carousel-image
            title = Home Slider
            description = A content element to add one or more images
            tt_content_defValues.CType = rapigo_home_slider
        }
    }
    show := addToList(rapigo_home_slider)
}
```

`EXT:rapigo\Configuration\TCA\Overrides\tt_content_my_extension_my_slider.php`

[image]

`Ext:rapigo\Configuration\TypoScript\myslider.typoscript`

```
tt_content {
    my_extension_my_slider < lib.contentElement
    my_extension_my_slider {
        templateName = HomeSlider
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10.references.fieldName = assets
        }
    }
}
```

All these codes enables a section in backend from where I can add slider content. But while redering it on front end there is an error

`ERROR: Content Element with uid "26" and type "rapigo_home_slider" has no rendering definition!`

I definitely missed something and I have no idea what I have to do. I am new in Typo3.

So my question is:
1) How could I define the template for my slider? Please also suggest the path where I have to write the code.
2) After it how could I get data from the content element so I can grab it from there and put it in my html design.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a fluid template file to the set of templates files already defined.

there probably is a definition like

```
lib.contentElement.templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

As you never should modify the core itself (don't even add files to these folders) you need to add further folders with your folder path like:

```
lib.contentElement.templateRootPaths.5 = EXT:rapigo/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

there you have the template file `HomeSlider.html`. in that file you could do a

```
<f:debug title="all data available in HomeSlider.html">{_all}</f:debug>
```

and see what data you could use to work with. you should find a `data` object which contains all fields from the tt_content record.

Aside from `templateRootPaths` you also can add values for `layoutRootPaths` and `partialRootpaths` to enhance the set of available templates.